# Step Functions - Use output from older step in later step (non-sequential)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

In a state machine with 3 steps, is it possible for step 3 to use the output of step 1? In my specific scenario I have:

```
Task -> Map State -> Task
```

where I'm specifically interested in using the Map State's input for its first iteration as the input for Step 3. I *could* handle the entire input to the map state as well, but so far I'm not seeing how to achieve either of these.

Answer (score 4):

`"ResultPath":"$.mapOutput"` will prefix `mapOutput` to output of the map. and combined input and output will be send as input to following task.

This is input to Step 3:

```
{
  "Comment": "Insert your JSON here",
  "inputForMap": [
    "iter 1",
    "iter2"
  ],
  "mapOutput": [
    "iter 1",
    "iter2"
  ]
}
```

Here is entire definition

```
{
   "StartAt":"Dummy Step 1 Output",
   "States":{
      "Dummy Step 1 Output":{
         "Type":"Pass",
         "Result":[
            "iter 1",
            "iter2"
         ],
         "ResultPath":"$.inputForMap",
         "Next":"loop on map"
      },
      "loop on map":{
         "Type":"Map",
         "ResultPath":"$.mapOutput",
         "Next":"Step three",
         "Iterator":{
            "StartAt":"Step 2 - Looping on map",
            "States":{
               "Step 2 - Looping on map":{
                  "Type":"Pass",
                  "End":true
               }
            }
         },
         "ItemsPath":"$.inputForMap",
         "MaxConcurrency":1
      },
      "Step three":{
         "Type":"Pass",
         "Next":"End of Step Function"
      },
      "End of Step Function":{
         "Type":"Pass",
         "End":true
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

Step three Input:
[image]

Comment: That doesn't work. From what I can tell, that just prefixes the map state output with `mapOutput`. The output I'm getting from the map state is the `Attempts` array which contains a bunch of metadata about each iteration

Comment: so, entire array of `Attempts` will be going out as `mapOutput.Attempts` and step three input will be combined input and output of step two? the first block is the input of the step 3, `Comment` is input step function , `inputForMap` is input of step two, `mapOutput` is output of step three.

Answer (score 1):

I found out, all I needed to do was set `ResultPath: null` on Step 2, and it would pass the input straight through

Comment: we will not be able to use out of step 2 at all with `ResultPath: null` , where as with `ResultPath: someVariable` (like my answer) will append the out of step 2 to `someVariable` , so, we have access to input as well as output of step 2, in step 3.

Comment: That's fair. In this case though, Step 2 doesn't produce any meaningful output, which is my question was how to make Step 1 output the input to Step 3, not combine them. I appreciate the answer though, it was educational.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to discard the output, you need to use `ResultPath: null`, this will maintain the original input without any change (You can check more details about the ResultPath  [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-resultpath.html)). Take in consideration that the default value for **`ResultPath`** is **`$`**, which means that the state will overwrite the entire context with the result of the step, that why you were losing all the previous context in your state machine.

Another solution, in case you need the result of the step 2 in your workflow, is to write the result in a new node, like Balu Vyamajala explained in his answer.